# How to subdivide a rectangle?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm looking to divide a rectangle up into smaller cells while trying to keep the cells close to the same size. I’m trying to keep the cells widths and heights similar. Aspect ratio of 1:1 or closest to that.

Examples:

Number of blocks = 1

[image: one]

```
return rectangle
```

Number of blocks = 2

[image: two]

```
return splitCell(rectangle)
```

Number of blocks = 3

[image: three]

```
const cells = splitCell(rectangle)
return [...splitCell(cells[0]), cells[1]]
```

Number of blocks = 4

[image: four]

```
const cells = splitCell(rectangle)
return [...splitCell(cells[0]), ...splitCell(cells[1])]
```

Number of blocks = 5

This is where it starts getting tricky. Firstly the one row has a different number of cells. Secondly the cells in row 1 are a different size to row 2.

[image: five]

```
?
```

Number of blocks = 41

[image: 41]

```
?
```

The split cell function

```
const splitCell = (cell): Array => cell.width > cell.height ? splitByWidth(cell) : splitByHeight(cell)
```

My initial solution was to find the largest sided cell and divide that but at a certain point most cells have the same dimensions so it ends up with a group of smaller cells on one side:

[image: 41 actual]

Something like:

```
for (let i = 1; i < n; i++) {
  // findBiggest(cells)
  // splitCell(biggestCell)
  // add splitCell in to result array
}
```

But I am looking for a solution where most of the cells have a similar aspect ratio

Comment: is it a problem only with odd `Number of blocks`?

Comment: The sketch where you divide into 5 cells seems off. I would expect the top-left cell to split in two. Otherwise there seems to be no logic if you would split horizontally or vertically. Now it seems like that the longest side should be split.

Comment: @AloisChristen you’re right. I realised the missing requirement after I posted. I’m trying to keep the cells widths and heights similar. Aspect ratio of 1:1

Comment: Your requirement "Aspect ratio of 1:1" is wrong. The initial shape is not a square !

Comment: Or closest to 1:1 @YvesDaoust

Comment: @grabury: no, not 1:1, *it's not a square*.

Comment: @YvesDaoust subdivide the side that is longer which will get closer and closer to a square the more cells you add

Comment: I see. Then my solution is wrong.

Comment: @YvesDaoust thanks for the help. I appreciate it. Maybe my mental model is incorrect. I'm struggling to explain it.

Comment: I have updated my answer, but it is not really complete.

Comment: This is an optimization problem of sorts.  I think you need to define some metric you want to optimize, whether it's variance of areas, mean aspect ratio, closest mean aspect ratio to the original, or something else.  Not that I know how to optimize any of these, but I think there needs to be a target.

Comment: I responded to a problem similar in nature at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64733527/algorithm-for-optimal-square-size-in-canvas/64792753#64792753.  You might be able to retrofit as the algorithm I proposed returns optional best fit configurations given the number of desired cells...

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you would like to use N squares of area W.H/N, i.e. of side √(W.H/N). So the number of squares per sides should be U=√(N.W/H)) in width and V=√(N.H/W)) in height, or the closest integers.

So you can form the subdivision in U.V squares, and add or remove one cell per row or per column (and rearrange evenly) to adjust to N.

As a fine tuning, you can also adjust the heights of the two different row types by using a penalty value (that rates the discrepancy to the ideal ratio; for instance, the absolute difference of the area and the ideal area W.H/N) and minimize the total penalty.

Comment: Your answer has helped me but I think this would give me cells with aspect ratios similar to the containing rectangle / page. To get 1:1 aspect ratio you could work out how many rows and columns. Check the aspect ratio of the last cell: if width is greater than height add a new cell, if height is greater than width add a new column.... something like that?